Restore a snapshot on a new instance
I just wondering if it's possible to restore snapshot in a different instance.
For example:
I have an instance named "bluey". I made a snapshot of "bluey" today with name "bluey-new-home".
1 year late. I created a new instance named "bingo". Can I restore the snapshot "bluey-new-home" to "bingo" instance?
The reason I ask this is because my multipass instances crashed quite many times and they were not repairable and recoverable. So I thought the best solution is to make a snapshot as soon as I created the instance with all softwares installed and configured. Then save a snapshot of the instance at that time.
If the instance ever crashes, I can use the snapshot to quickly rebuild a new instance withint a minute.
All solutions and opinions are welcome and appreciated!

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

The instance is using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm using multipass 1.13.1+mac on MacOS. Hope that gives some helpful information.
